# Alternative to long, non-interrumpible method in a java/android thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, bigdecimal, java-threads

In the UI Thread in an Android application, I need to run a method which can take nanoseconds or forever to complete. I think I cannot exactly determine when it'll take forever, so I'm running it in a separate thread through a pool.

```java
myPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(new ThreadFactory(){
    //override newThread(Runnable r)...
});

Future<Result> futureResult = myPool.submit(new Callable<Result>(){
    @Override public Result call(){
        return dangerousMethod();
    }
});
```

For demonstrating purposes, I block the UI for a second and then, if the method hasn't finished, I move on.

```java
try{
    Result result = futureResult.get(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    //Use result here
}catch(TimeoutException e) {//Other Exceptions are ommited
    futureResult.cancel(true);
    Log.d("DEMO", "Method takes too long. Skip");
}
```

I try to cancel the future and interrupt its thread with `futureResult.cancel(true)`, but the `dangerousMethod()` won't respond to interruptions, so the thread will keep running until it eventually completes its task.

What I've tried: Subclassing a `ThreadPoolExecutor` and get the private `Thread`s through reflection (`ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.thread`) to force (Bad Practices TM) either a `stop()` (not working because `UnsupportedOperationException`) or a `stop0()` (also non-working because `NoSuchMethodException`). More details on this:

```java
class MyPool extends ThreadPoolExecutor{
    //constructor, reflection code to get the Threads, etc

    void cancelThread(Thread thread){
        try {
            thread.stop();
        }catch(SecurityException | UnsupportedOperationException e) {
            try {
                Method stopMethod = Thread.class.getDeclaredMethod("stop0", Object.class);
                stopMethod.setAccessible(true);
                stopMethod.invoke(thread, new ThreadDeath());
            }catch(NoSuchMethodException | 
                   InvocationTargetException | 
                   IllegalAccessException x)
            {
                Log.d("MyPool", "Can't stop thread", x);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The dangerous method is  actually like this:

```java
BigDecimal n1 = new BigDecimal("1E1000000");
BigDecimal n2 = new BigDecimal("1");
BigDecimal result = n1.add(n2);//Takes too long
```

I could check every BigDecimal method I use for the numbers it handles well, but I'd first like to know wether I'm missing something obvious or there is another approach. Because

```java
BigDecimal n3 = new BigDecimal("1E999999");
BigDecimal result = n1.add(n3);
```

works well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems that you cannot forcefully kill a Java thread in Android - in a Oracle Java it actually still works. The reason is that in Oracle Java `stop()` calls `stop1()`, while on Android it calls `stop(new ThreadDeath())` which in turn unconditionally throws `UnsupportedOperationException`.

But why bother forcing it to stop? Just let it run in the background, forget it and go on. Sure you have some risk of bogging memory and CPU, but as you said only some of the numers cause the method to run that long, so chances are that you can forget this very thread and be able to succesfully start most of others.

If the long running background thread tries to do actions after being finished you can just set a flag telling him to shut up. As long as you don't need its result you are good.

Comment: That's what I'm doing now: abandone the thread working alone with a low priority. But I feel responsible of using 1 CPU core just for nothing.

Comment: You're completely right - it's your responsibility. And it's really a pity you can't kill useless threads... But at the end your most important responsibility is to make your app responsive.

Comment: Accepted. I finally let the threads run alone but then I'm also setting an alarm at Activity.onStop() to kill the app when it's not being used. That's how I kill threads.

Comment: "But why bother forcing it to stop? Just let it run in the background, forget it and go on" bro! Specially sometimes, some f#ing libraries use data to download stuff, like if we started a download and they can not get interupted, all we can do is, to kill them. And the speech u said, is absolutely very disappointing to hear

Comment: It's not here to satisfy your expectation but to share my experience with the one asking the question. No less and no more. I haven't found any other solution and for my use case it was a legitimate solution. If you know something better why don't you answer yourself?